# How to xor hex value in Python (1 bit answer)

Tags: python

lets say i have the following variable
data=0xab12cd30
i would like to get the xor over the 32 bits (for example in verilog ^data)

for example (giving 8bit examples)

data = 0x11 -> result should be 0

data = 0x10 -> result shoule be 1

data = 0x21 -> result should be 0

data = 0x23 -> result should be 1

What is the easiest way?
Using Python 2.4.3

Comment: you want `xor` by what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest? Maybe this:

```
bin(data).count('1') % 2
```

Demo:

```
>>> for data in 0x11, 0x10, 0x21, 0x23:
        print bin(data).count('1') % 2

0
1
0
1
```

**Edit:** If using an awfully old Python that doesn't have `bin`, here's a do-it-yourself solution:

```
for data in 0x11, 0x10, 0x21, 0x23:
    xor = 0
    while data:
        xor ^= data & 1
        data >>= 1
    print xor
```

**Edit 2:** A faster and more tricky solution:

```
for data in 0x11, 0x10, 0x21, 0x23:
xor = 0
while data:
    xor ^= 1
    data &= data - 1      # deletes the last 1-bit
print xor
```

Comment: Hmm, i dont have the bin method (Version 2.4.3)...
i dont mind to iterate over each bit, by how do i do it?

Comment: @Jonathan Ugh... nobody should still be using such an old version :-). But ok, I added another solution to my answer.

Comment: @Jonathan And now I added another, less easy but faster and more interesting one.